# How to resample a 2-D spatial matrix (not a time series) using a weighted average to from the 1km grid to the 0.25 degree

Tags: python, gis, satellite-image, spatial-interpolation, bilinear-interpolation

I have a bumpy matrix A with shape [num_X, num_Y]. The corresponding lattitude and longitude array is A_lat (of size [num_Y,1]) and A_lon (of size [num_X,1]). And the each element of this matrix for example A[i, j] represents a value of geophysical variable (for example, leaf area index) at latitude A_lat[j] and longitude A_lon[I].

Now the matrix A is of resolution 1km, while I want to resample it to a resolution of 0.25 degree by using `weighted average`. So how can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: You should provide a code of what you tried to do. If you do not know where to begin, try to build a grid of lat/lon with a step of 0.25 degree that contains the min/max of your latitude and longitude. This new grid contains the indices on which you want to interpolate your data and the original grid of A_lat and A_lon contains the indices on which you have actual values, you should be able to find an interpolation method that expects such inputs.

Comment: well, I just have the data...and I think the problem description is clear enough which does not need a code for describing what I tried to do...

Comment: The code to provide is not for describing your issue but to demonstrate a first attempt of resolving your problem by yourself. In my previous comment you can find the steps to perform the interpolation you want.